# XSLT to remove soap envelope and soap namespaces and process the soap body

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, ibm-datapower, ibm-api-management, ibm-api-connect

I need to remove the soap envelope and soap namespace from the input and pass it to the backend as xml
For e.g:
My input is

```
<xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soapenvelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
 <soap:Body>
 <tem:Data xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 <tem:DATE>string</tem:DATE> 
 <tem:STATUS>string</tem:STATUS> 
 <tem:CODE>string</tem:CODE>
 </tem:Data>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

my expected output is:

```
<Data>
 <DATE>string</DATE> 
 <STATUS>string</STATUS> 
 <CODE>string</CODE>
 </Data>
```

iam using the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="comment()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
<xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:value-of select="/Body"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but iam getting the below output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
 <Body>
 <Data>
 <DATE>string</IDATE> 
 <STATUS>string</STATUS> 
 <CODE>string</CODE>
 </Data>
 </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be sufficient to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this code just did exactly what i wanted, thank you for the help.